# Pandas: Mask/Where using date [Must not use date as index]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

```
print(testSeries)

#output
2848   2020-10-03 14:52:44
2849   2020-10-03 14:54:26
2850   2020-10-04 01:52:01
2851                   NaT
2852                   NaT
Name: 4, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

As can be see, the dtype is datetime64 as I have converted element to a datetime from a string already. If I isolate a single element, things like element.day or element.hour do work properly. (testSeries.iloc[0].day work)

Now, I want to create a boolean mask like so:

```
print(testSeries.day == 3)

#Expected Output
[True, True, False, False, False]


# ACTUAL output
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'day'
```

I would like to filter by any combination of day,month,year,hour,minute etc. Yet this method is not working.

Either I have to use a for-loop and check every element
OR
use a newly defined function and map it to this series to create a boolean mask.

Any simpler solution that works similar to the one I tried but failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.dt` ancestor:

```
print(testSeries.dt.day == 3)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: 4, dtype: bool
```

It working same if column:

```
#if 4 is string
print(df['4'].dt.day == 3)

#if 4 is int
print(df[4].dt.day == 3)
```

For filter use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), not `where`:

```
df1 = df[df[4].dt.day == 3]
```

Comment: Thankyou! One more thing, How do I apply a filter to the whole dataframe that consists of similar series?